# AWS API Gateway client certificates in Go lang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-api-gateway, client-certificates

I'm trying to secure connection between AWS API Gateway and my API endpoint services exactly as it is described int his documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html

AFAIK I need to copy the cert form AWS API Gateway and use `http.ListenAndServeTLS` method. But it accepts two files: **keyFile** and **certFile** 
`func ListenAndServeTLS(addr, certFile, keyFile string, handler Handler)`.

When I click on copy link (see image below)
[image: example of certificate generated by AWS]

the only thing I get is the certificate in such format (I've shortened it for explanation purposes):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIC6TCCAdGgAwIBAgIJAKbyiCf2f5J2MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMDQxCzAJBgNV
fYe+dxR0PMFvfUpZaGgaY1ykQG1sNaw/b6NjNg9c1aEVSZ7b1eU/cBmb6XqHw0Ih
7yHtBm+p8Px4NMAT9YhytTxPRBYpApfUsfPMa3qfUWvvj4TD0LR6bW980bebyxUn
BigXToSFlPeiNGdU/Zpiw9crzplojNBFc=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

So my question is, how exactly I need to configure `ListenAndServeTLS` method to make sure the any request to my service is from API Gateway? Where I can find private key? It's quite confusing for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client certificate AWS is given you is for authenticating the client that send requests to your service, which is the AWS gateway.

This cert is not to be used to start your server, but to authenticates requests.

See an example of use below, untested code, but as a lead.

```
func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "hello, world!\n")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/hello", Hello)

    certBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("aws-gateway.pem")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    block, certBytes := pem.Decode(certBytes)

    cert, err := x509.ParseCertificate(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
    }

    clientCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    clientCertPool.AddCerts(cert)

    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        ClientCAs: clientCertPool,
        // NoClientCert
        // RequestClientCert
        // RequireAnyClientCert
        // VerifyClientCertIfGiven
        // RequireAndVerifyClientCert
        ClientAuth: tls.RequireAndVerifyClientCert,
    }
    tlsConfig.BuildNameToCertificate()

    server := &http.Server{
        Addr:      ":8080",
        TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
    }

    server.ListenAndServeTLS("server.crt", "server.key")
}
```

This way, your service will require that all requests provide a certificate and will verify it against the pool of ClientCA. You could, of course, add more certificates to the client pool if desired.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. But I still don't know from where i can get the `server.crt` and `server.key` files. Your example gives me an error:
`open server.crt: no such file or directory`

Comment: This is the certificate and keys for the server, your service. Either generate a self signed one (not sure it will work with AWS, or get one for free with Let's Encrypt).

Comment: @WilliamPoussier The issue the OP is referring to is that AWS offers a client certificate but describes no method to actually get a file copy of the pem keys. I assume you could use http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/apigateway/get-client-certificate.html to get the PEM certificate as a string and then make a PEM and insert the text. Although it is a self signed certificate so likely Let's Encrypt is still more secure.